# How often do AirTags beep when unattended?

Tags: airtag

I understand that when AirTags are left unattended by their owner, they will beep at some point between 8-12 hours (chosen randomly), to discourage tracking people.

I have my AirTags in various pieces of luggage, some of which I plan to keep in storage. Therefore it will trigger this initial beep.

My questions are:

1. How often after that initial beep will it continue beeping?
2. What do these beeps sound like (Number of beeps, volume, etc)? Bonus points if I can simulate the beep to hear it exactly without needing to wait 8 hours.

The reason I ask is if it’s too frequent or too annoying, I’ll likely want to remove the AirTag so that it doesn’t disturb people at the storage facility.

Comment: My understanding is that this only occurs when the item is found to be moving, but I may be wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AirTag only gives separation alerts ("beeping") when moved around. Having it in a piece of luggage in storage won't trigger this.